# Appium - Element not found 404, but appium is still passing the testcase

Tags: node.js, webdriver, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

[debug] [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'no such element' to NoSuchElementError
[debug] [W3C (4950e230)] Encountered internal error running command: NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
[debug] [W3C (4950e230)]     at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.findElOrEls (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\find.js:75:11)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/4950e230-f5d2-4d8d-acd2-56e604e560b9/element 404

Comment: Are these logs from appium server?

Comment: Yes


**this is the code**.
`selector{
yourTip: ‘//android.widget.TextView[@text=“asflnaksjfhhfosah”]’, }

// this filed is not present on a particular page but and 5-sec appium passes my script. I changed the text just to confirm if it picks it up or not
and here is the expected result.
Expected Result:
expect(Ticket.yourTip.isDisplayed());`

Comment: Weird. I am also using appium with webdriverio. We were struggling to make appium locate available elements. But your case is so different. It is identifying an element that is not available.